# Failed while inserting data to access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, .net-4.0

This is code to insert to database microsoft access , 
but error appear.that said *insert into* error 
please tell me why it gonna be like that. and give me idea how to solve this problem.

thanks

first collect data from textbox then 
and then the code select the datatable
and then put in dataset
after that insert to database.
I dont see the problem

```
    If txtCode.Text = "" Then
        txtCode.Focus()
    ElseIf cmbCneeName.Text = "" Then
        cmbCneeName.Focus()
    ElseIf txtCneeAddress1.Text = "" Then
        txtCneeAddress1.Focus()
    ElseIf txtCneeAddress2.Text = "" Then
        txtCneeAddress2.Focus()

    Else

        Dim acces_da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim cm As OleDbCommand
        Dim acces_ds As DataSet
        Dim datarowtblshipper As DataRow
        Dim cmdbuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder

        cm = New OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = DBconnection()
            .CommandText = "select * from TblConsignee where con_code='" & txtCode.Text & "'"
        End With


        acces_da = New OleDbDataAdapter
        acces_ds = New DataSet
        acces_da.SelectCommand = cm
        cmdbuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(acces_da)
        acces_da.Fill(acces_ds)
        Try
            datarowtblshipper = acces_ds.Tables(0).NewRow
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Code") = txtCode.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Comp") = cmbCneeName.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Add1") = txtCneeAddress1.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Add2") = txtCneeAddress2.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Add3") = txtCneeAddress3.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Add4") = txtCneeAddress4.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_PCode") = txtCneePostCode.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_tel") = txtCneePhoneNo.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Contents") = txtCneeContents.Text
            datarowtblshipper("destination") = txtDestination.Text
            datarowtblshipper("Con_Cont") = txtAttention.Text
            datarowtblshipper("zone") = tzone.Text


            acces_ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(datarowtblshipper)
            cmdbuilder.GetInsertCommand()
            acces_da.Update(acces_ds)
            MsgBox("New Data Inserted!")

        Catch
            MsgBox("Error occured : " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "error")
        End Try
    End If
```

[image: This is the error they said..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Access databases regularly.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the method you are using as I am still relatively new to VB.NET.

Try this method, it's easier to keep track of errors:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
                           "Data Source = " '''Your path here
    Dim sql_insert As String = "INSERT INTO TblConsignee (Con_Code, Con_Comp, Con_Add1, " & _
                               "Con_Add2, Con_Add3, Con_Add4, Con_PCode, Con_tel, " & _
                               "Contents, destination, Con_Cont, zone) " & _
                               "VALUES " & _ 
                               "(@code, @comp, @add1, @add2, @add3, @add4, @pcode, " & _
                               "@tel, @content, @dest, @zone);"

    Dim sql_insert_entry As New OleDbCommand

    con.Open()

    With sql_insert_entry
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtCode.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@comp", cmbCneeName.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@add1", txtCneeAddress1.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@add2", txtCneeAddress2.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@add3", txtCneeAddress3.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@add4", txtCneeAddress4.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", txtCneePostCode.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", txtCneePhoneNo.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", txtCneeContents.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dest", txtDestination.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cont", txtAttention.Text)
          .Parameters.AddWithValue("@zone", tzone.Text)
          .CommandText = sql_insert
          .Connection = con
          .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    con.Close()

End Using
```

If you are updating a record, just change the command string to update the desired fields of your database.

Comment: i like your code.., that can be used.. , actually i try to fill all data to dataset and then using the dataset to update the database..

using functiong GetInsertCommand(), they have GetUpdateCommand and even GetDeleteCommand.

Comment: Im glad it helped.